# Windows Media Services development in VS2012 (C++)

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-studio-2012, sdk

I have an application that creates WMSPublishingPoint. After migration to VS2012 (from VS2010) I can't compile the project due to studio can't see 'wmsserver.h' file.
This file is shipped with WindowsSDK 7.1, but there is no such file in SDK for Windows 8.
If I choose platform toolset vs110_xp - it's OK. But I need the v110 toolset.

Here is a link which confirm that developers can use wmsserver.h in development for Windows 8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd874782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
I tried to reinstall SDK (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/hh852363), but it didn't help.

Is there any additional link to install Windows Media Services SDK for VS2012? I haven't necessary files after installation of Windows SDK for Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is removed, probably because [the component is not supported on Windows Server 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/randomnumber/archive/2012/11/14/windows-media-services-not-supported-on-windows-server-2012.aspx).

I suggest you to extract the WMS facing code to a separate DLL that uses the vs110_xp set, and use the DLL in your application.